# Haskell - arithmetic operations with datatypes

Tags: haskell

I was writing my own haskell datatype to resolve a sum operation with integers, but i dont know how to make the semantic .

```
data Expr = Value Int
    | Sum Expr Expr
```

I was trying to do:

```
sum:: Expr -> Expr -> Int
sum a b = b + a
val:: Int -> Int
val a = a
```

I want to write like:

```
Sum (Value 3) (Value 5)
```

And get 8 as return, any ideas?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: `Sum (Value 3) (Value 5)` will *always*, by definition, be a distinct value of type `Expr`; you can't reduce it to `8`, because `8` is not a constructor for `Expr`.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, in this sort of situation, you write an "evaluator" or "interpreter" -- a single function that accepts an `Expr` and evaluates it to a value:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
```

Then, you can write:

```
> eval (Sum (Value 3) (Value 5))
8
>
```

Haskell's pattern matching for function definitions makes this very elegant:

```
eval (Value x) = ...
eval (Sum e1 e2) = ...you'll need to use eval recursively here...
```

So, instead of writing multiple functions, one for each component of your `Expr`, you write a single function with one pattern-based *definition* for each component.

If this was homework, you might want to stop here and try to figure the details out for yourself.  If it wasn't, then the following should work:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Value x) = x
eval (Sum e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `sum` appropriately for each combination of data constructors.

```
sum :: Expr -> Expr -> Int
sum (Value x) (Value y) = x + y
sum (Sum a b) (Sum c d) = sum a b + sum c d
sum (Value x) (Sub a b) = x + sum a b
sum (Sum a b) (Value y) = sum a b + y
```

This can be simplified; one way is with a helper function that reduces a single `Expr` to an integer value first.

```
value :: Expr -> Int
value (Value x) = x
value (Sum x y) = (value x) + (value y)

sum :: Expr -> Expr -> Int
sum x y = value x + value y
```